# Canvas.drawBitmap() fails on Android 9 device

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm using `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null)` to render an image (bitmap) onto a custom view, where `matrix` performs scaling and translation. This works perfectly on emulated devices in Android Studio, but when testing on an Android 9 mobile device (Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact), the rendering fails at higher magnification -- nothing is rendered, but there are no errors.

Has anyone experienced similar problems with `drawBitmap` on any device? Are there any known bugs, workarounds?

As an alternative, I also tried rendering the image using `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null)` where the `sourceRect` and `destRect` rectangles are calculated to perform the same scaling and translation. This gives identical results, the rendering still fails specifically on my Android 9 device.

I do not see the problem when testing on an emulated device running Android 9. I'm guessing it might be related to some GPU operation on the Sony Xperia, but I have not seen any graphics problems with other apps on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It seems that the problem was caused by some kind of memory limitation on the Sony Xperia. I replaced my image drawing class with [davemorrissey's excellent implementation](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view), and found that the problem goes away when sourcing the image directly from a URI, avoiding loading the bitmap directly into memory. When sourcing the image from a bitmap in memory (like I did before), the same problem appeared again. I saw no memory allocation errors, but possibly some limit on the GPU or in other layers was exceeded.